# How to access variables from a different class

Tags: java, android

I have 2 classes called `Game.java` and `KeyInput.java`. How do I access int x and int y from `Game.java` and use to in `KeyInput.java`?

**Game.java**

```
public class Game extends JFrame {

  int x, y;

  //Constructor
  public Game(){
    setTitle("Game");
    setSize(300, 300);
    setResizable(false);
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.addKeyListener(new KeyInput());

    x = 150;
    y = 150;
  }

  public void paint(Graphics g){
    g.fillRect( x, y, 15, 15);
  }

  public static void main(String [] args){
    new Game();
  } 
}
```

**KeyInput.java**

```
public class KeyInput extends KeyAdapter {

  public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();

    if(keyCode == e.VK_W)
      y--; //Error here saying "y cannot be resolved to a variable"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are having is with the scope. There are many ways to fix this, such as using static variables or passing a pointer to the object that contains the variables you want to access. I'll just give you two.

Static: Not recommended but works well for small programs. You can only have one set of x and y. If you have two instantiations of Game, they will share the same values.

```
public class Game extends JFrame {
  //make this static and public so it can be accessed anywhere.
  public static int x, y;
  ...
  }
  ...
  public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
    int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();

    if(keyCode == e.VK_W)
      Game.y--; //Static access
  }
```

Pass-in method:

```
public class KeyInput extends KeyAdapter {
  Game game; //need a pointer to the original class object that holds x and y. Save it here
  public KeyInput(Game g){ //get the object pointer when this class is created.
    this.game = g;
  }

  public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
    int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();

    if(keyCode == e.VK_W)
       game.y--; //now a local variable we can access
  }
}


public class Game extends JFrame {
  //make these public
  public int x, y;

  //Constructor
  public Game(){
    setTitle("Game");
    setSize(300, 300);
    setResizable(false);
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.addKeyListener(new KeyInput(this)); //pass the pointer in here 
...
```

Comment: Hey, no problem! :)